# Restricting Word Count in tinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am using tinyMCE on a textarea. In order to limit the number of words that can be entered I have this script in my page.

```
    tinyMCE.init({
            mode : "exact",
            elements : "description",
            theme : "advanced",
            plugins : "paste,wordcount", 
            theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,|,sub,sup,|,cut,copy,pastetext,|,undo,redo,|,code",
            theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
            theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",      
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
            force_p_newlines : false,
            valid_elements : "p,br,b,u,sub,sup,strong,em,hr",
             theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
         //Word counter
         theme_advanced_path : false,
         setup : function(ed) {
              ed.onKeyUp.add(function(ed, e) { 
                var strip = (tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()).replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
                var words = strip.split(' ').length;
                if (words < maxwords) {
                    var text = "You have used " + words + " words, " +  (maxwords - words) + " remaining"
                }else if (words == maxwords){
                    var text = "<span style='color:red'>You have reached your full word allocation</span>"
                }else if (words > maxwords){
                    var text = "<span style='color:red;font-weight:bold'>You have exceeded your word allocation.</span>"
                }
            tinymce.DOM.setHTML(tinymce.DOM.get(tinyMCE.activeEditor.id + '_path_row'), text); 
if (words >= maxwords) {
    e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
return false;
}
    });
  }
 });
```

This very neatly puts a warning message under the text area, and stops the user submitting the form with more than the allowed words.

However as it stands everything is locked once the word count is exceeded. My aim is to keep it working for the delete and backspace buttons so that the user can easily correct an excess word count. I have tried various things along the lines of

```
if (words >= maxwords && e.keycode != 8) {
```

but nothing seems to work. Surely I'm on the right lines here. Am I missing something obvious?

Incidentally "maxwords" is defined in another place and there is also a PHP limitation on the number of words that can be submitted to the database.

**EDIT** Modified the code and question as I have made some partial progress to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it. I discovered that Firefox doesn't like "keycode" and I was testing in Firefox. I have now changed the line to

```
if (words >= maxwords && e.which != 8 && e.which != 46 && e.keycode != 8 && e.keycode != 46) {
```

Now the textarea is frozen when the maximum word count is reached, but the delete and backspace buttons can be used to bring the word count down below the maximum.

I would still like the warning messages to show as soon as the page is visible instead of when the user has started typing, but perhaps that's a task for another day.